# `new Date("2013-08-08T09:40")` not working in jweek calendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, jquery-week-calendar

I have problem with `jquery weekcalendar demo plugin` Its work in Mozilla but not in Chrome .

I Found Problem its with `Datetime` :

In `DEMO.JS` File :

```
  alert(new Date("2013-08-08T09:40"));
```

so its work with Mozilla Firefox  with output Its fine

[image]

But in Chrome (Version 28.0.1500.95m) its not working :
Wrong output :

[image]

So please help me out . I need same output with chrome also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper format is

```
new Date("2013-08-08T09:40Z");
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

If you want to play the local timezone game then you must manually calculate the offset you want and use it in the format:

```
new Date("2013-08-08T09:40+05:30");
```

It is easier to just use UTC though.

If you don't want to specify any timezone, you need to use different constructor:

```
new Date(2013, 7, 8, 9, 40);
```

This will result in an instant that is dependent on whatever timezone settings the user has on their computer.

Comment: `@Esailija' Thanks for ans :
Its work fine with `new Date("2013-08-08T09:40+05:30");`

But in `Mozilla` its work without `timezone` its handle automatically 
So i don't understand  why its not fine with `chrome `

Comment: @ankit337 The simplest way to explain it is: when you pass crap in, you get crap out. For example, if you wrote incorrect html, then the result will appear most likely differently in every browser.